# Transforming nested arrays in Office 365 logs into table

Tags: logs, jq

I want to release a simple tool based on jq to transform some common Office 365 Unified Audit Log events into a tabular report format, but having challenges with the way certain key arrays are nested. In particular, when i get down to Folders[] that contain sets of Ids, Paths, and FolderItems[] that contain rows of message IDs and sizes, I can't figure out a way to make the related values from the arrays stay in sync / collate - instead I am getting massive combinations of every value as though I'm unintentionally iterating through them.

Here's some sample data:

```
{"CreationTime":"2024-02-06T12:13:14","Id":"abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888","Operation":"MailItemsAccessed","ResultStatus":"Succeeded","UserId":"admin@example.com","ClientIPAddress":"5.5.5.5","Folders":[{"FolderItems":[{"InternetMessageId":"<abc1234@aaabbbccc.whatever.com>","SizeInBytes":12345},{"InternetMessageId":"<cccccc@aaabbbccc.whatever.com>","SizeInBytes":11122},{"InternetMessageId":"<final@host.gmail.com>","SizeInBytes":88888}],"Id":"EEEEEEEE","Path":"\\Outbox"},{"FolderItems":[{"InternetMessageId":"<otherid@host.com>","SizeInBytes":44444},{"InternetMessageId":"<furtherhost@xyz.host2.com>","SizeInBytes":100000},{"InternetMessageId":"<id7@bbb.outlook.com>","SizeInBytes":109000},{"InternetMessageId":"<other@hosthost.com>","SizeInBytes":22000},{"InternetMessageId":"<junk@b8b8b8.newhost.com>","SizeInBytes":333333}],"Id":"FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAB","Path":"\\Inbox"}]}
{"CreationTime":"2024-02-06T20:00:00","Id":"abcdabcd-1234-1234-6666-9999999999999","Operation":"MailItemsAccessed","ResultStatus":"Succeeded","UserId":"other@other.cc","ClientIPAddress":"7.7.7.7","Folders":{"FolderItems":[{"InternetMessageId":"<example@aaabbbccc.whatever.com>","SizeInBytes":77777},{"InternetMessageId":"<cccccc4@aaabbbccc.whatever.com>","SizeInBytes":888888},{"InternetMessageId":"<final3@host.gmail.com>","SizeInBytes":99999}],"Id":"12341234","Path":"\\Temp"}}
```

Desired output:

| ﻿CreationTime | Id | UserId | ClientIPAddress | FolderId | FolderPath | InternetMessageId | SizeInBytes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-02-06T12:13:14 | abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888 | admin@example.com | 5.5.5.5 | EEEEEEEE | \Outbox | abc1234@aaabbbccc.whatever.com | 12345 |
| 2024-02-06T12:13:14 | abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888 | admin@example.com | 5.5.5.5 | EEEEEEEE | \Outbox | cccccc@aaabbbccc.whatever.com | 11122 |
| 2024-02-06T12:13:14 | abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888 | admin@example.com | 5.5.5.5 | EEEEEEEE | \Outbox | final@host.gmail.com | 88888 |
| 2024-02-06T12:13:14 | abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888 | admin@example.com | 5.5.5.5 | FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAB | \Inbox | otherid@host.com | 44444 |
| 2024-02-06T12:13:14 | abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888 | admin@example.com | 5.5.5.5 | FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAB | \Inbox | furtherhost@xyz.host2.com | 100000 |
| 2024-02-06T12:13:14 | abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888 | admin@example.com | 5.5.5.5 | FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAB | \Inbox | id7@bbb.outlook.com | 109000 |
| 2024-02-06T12:13:14 | abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888 | admin@example.com | 5.5.5.5 | FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAB | \Inbox | other@hosthost.com | 22000 |
| 2024-02-06T12:13:14 | abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888 | admin@example.com | 5.5.5.5 | FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAB | \Inbox | junk@b8b8b8.newhost.com | 333333 |
| 2024-02-06T20:00:00 | 12341234 | other@other.cc | 7.7.7.7 | 12341234 | \Temp | example@aaabbbccc.whatever.com | 77777 |
| 2024-02-06T20:00:00 | 12341234 | other@other.cc | 7.7.7.7 | 12341234 | \Temp | cccccc4@aaabbbccc.whatever.com | 888888 |
| 2024-02-06T20:00:00 | 12341234 | other@other.cc | 7.7.7.7 | 12341234 | \Temp | final3@host.gmail.com | 99999 |

Note that the `.Folders` element can sometimes come in string format but that I was able to easily conditionally load using `fromjson`. For example:

`[...]"Folders": "[{\"FolderItems\":[{\"InternetMessageId\":\""Fo<abc1234@aaabbbccc.whatever.com>\",\"SizeInBytes\":12345},[...]`

Code so far:

```
cat | jq '
    if has("Folders") then
        if(.Folders | type=="string") and .Folders != "" then .Folders |= fromjson  end |
        if(.Folders | type=="string") and .Folders == "" then .Folders = null end
    end | .' |     # works up to here at least
    jq '
if has("Item") then .Item |= (if type=="string" and .!="" then fromjson else {} end) else .Item|={}  end |
    if has("Item") then
            if .Item | has("Id") then .ItemId = .Item.Id else .ItemId={} end |
            if .Item | has("ParentFolder") then
                .ItemParentFolderId=.Item.ParentFolder.Id? |
                    .ItemParentFolderPath=.Item.ParentFolder.Path? |
                    .ItemParentFolderName=.Item.ParentFolder.Name?
            end
        end | . ' | cat # works up to here at least
    jq '
    if has("Folders") then
        if (.Folders | select(type=="array")) then
            .Folders[].Id? |
            .FoldersPath=.Folders[].Path? |
            .FoldersFolderItems=.Folders[].FolderItems?
        else . end
    end
    ' |
jq -r '. | (.TimeGenerated // .CreationTime) as $EventTime |
.ClientIP = if .ClientIP == "" then null else .ClientIP end |
.ClientIP_ = if .ClientIP_ == "" then null else .ClientIP_ end |
.Client_IPAddress = if .Client_IPAddress == "" then null else .Client_IPAddress end |
.ClientIPAddress = if .ClientIPAddress == "" then null else .ClientIPAddress end |
.ActorIpAddress = if .ActorIpAddress == "" then null else .ActorIpAddress end |
(.ClientIP // .ClientIP_ // .Client_IPAddress // .ClientIPAddress // .ActorIpAddress) as $IPAddress |
(.UserId // .UserId_) as $LogonUser |
.FFIIMI as $InternetMessageId |
.FFISIB as $SizeInBytes |
{EventTime: $EventTime, IPAddress: $IPAddress, LogonUser: $LogonUser, InternetMessageId: $InternetMessageId, SizeInBytes: $SizeInBytes} + . |
[.Id, .EventTime, .IPAddress, .LogonUser, .MailboxOwnerUPN, .Operation, .InternetMessageId, .SizeInBytes] | @csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm starting with the JSON that you have provided as sample data. It is unclear whether this JSON is preprocessed in some way or not.

Since the top-level `Folders` array seems to *not* be an array if it contains a single item, we first need to turn it into an array if it isn't one already.  In `jq`, we can do that with

```
.Folders |= (if type == "array" then . else [.] end)
```

The general idea of the rest of the transformation is to duplicate the upper-level data, i.e. some of the key+value pairs from the top-most level and the `Id` and `Path` key from each `Folders` element, into the lowest level, the `FolderItems` elements.  We can then convert each `FolderItems` element into a CSV record.

To avoid keys with duplicate names, we also need to rename the `Folders` element's `Id` key to `FolderId` (and rename `Path` from the same level to `FolderPath`, for consistency).

The data from the top-most level that we want can be picked out and transferred down in an internal variable using

```
pick(.CreationTime, .Id, .UserId, .ClientIPAddress) as $record
```

This will create `$record` as

```json
{
  "CreationTime": "2024-02-06T12:13:14",
  "Id": "abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888",
  "UserId": "admin@example.com",
  "ClientIPAddress": "5.5.5.5"
}
```

... for the first JSON object.  Not that we get the keys in the order that we want them in the final CSV output.

We can then extract only the `Folders` elements with `.Folders[]` and pick out the `Id` and `Path` for each.  Since we want to rename these, we can't use `pick()` again, so we need to be a bit more hands-on:

```
.Folders[] | { FolderId: .Id, FolderPath: .Path } as $folder
```

We may then use `.FolderItems[]` to get a set of `FolderItems` elements, which we can add `$record` and `$folder` in front of:

```
.FolderItems[] | $record + $folder + .
```

As a single `jq` expression:

```
.Folders |= (if type == "array" then . else [.] end) |
pick(.CreationTime, .Id, .UserId, .ClientIPAddress) as $record |
.Folders[] | { FolderId: .Id, FolderPath: .Path } as $folder |
.FolderItems[] | $record + $folder + .
```

The result, given the data in the question:

```json
{
  "CreationTime": "2024-02-06T12:13:14",
  "Id": "abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888",
  "UserId": "admin@example.com",
  "ClientIPAddress": "5.5.5.5",
  "FolderId": "EEEEEEEE",
  "FolderPath": "\\Outbox",
  "InternetMessageId": "<abc1234@aaabbbccc.whatever.com>",
  "SizeInBytes": 12345
}
{
  "CreationTime": "2024-02-06T12:13:14",
  "Id": "abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888",
  "UserId": "admin@example.com",
  "ClientIPAddress": "5.5.5.5",
  "FolderId": "EEEEEEEE",
  "FolderPath": "\\Outbox",
  "InternetMessageId": "<cccccc@aaabbbccc.whatever.com>",
  "SizeInBytes": 11122
}
```

(etc.)

I would personally convert this set of JSON objects to CSV using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```bash
$ jq '.Folders |= (if type == "array" then . else [.] end) | pick(.CreationTime, .Id, .UserId, .ClientIPAddress) as $record | .Folders[] | { FolderId: .Id, FolderPath: .Path } as $folder | .FolderItems[] | $record + $folder + .' file | mlr --j2c cat
CreationTime,Id,UserId,ClientIPAddress,FolderId,FolderPath,InternetMessageId,SizeInBytes
2024-02-06T12:13:14,abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888,admin@example.com,5.5.5.5,EEEEEEEE,\Outbox,<abc1234@aaabbbccc.whatever.com>,12345
2024-02-06T12:13:14,abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888,admin@example.com,5.5.5.5,EEEEEEEE,\Outbox,<cccccc@aaabbbccc.whatever.com>,11122
2024-02-06T12:13:14,abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888,admin@example.com,5.5.5.5,EEEEEEEE,\Outbox,<final@host.gmail.com>,88888
2024-02-06T12:13:14,abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888,admin@example.com,5.5.5.5,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAB,\Inbox,<otherid@host.com>,44444
2024-02-06T12:13:14,abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888,admin@example.com,5.5.5.5,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAB,\Inbox,<furtherhost@xyz.host2.com>,100000
2024-02-06T12:13:14,abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888,admin@example.com,5.5.5.5,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAB,\Inbox,<id7@bbb.outlook.com>,109000
2024-02-06T12:13:14,abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888,admin@example.com,5.5.5.5,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAB,\Inbox,<other@hosthost.com>,22000
2024-02-06T12:13:14,abcdabcd-1234-1234-5555-888888888888,admin@example.com,5.5.5.5,FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAB,\Inbox,<junk@b8b8b8.newhost.com>,333333
2024-02-06T20:00:00,abcdabcd-1234-1234-6666-9999999999999,other@other.cc,7.7.7.7,12341234,\Temp,<example@aaabbbccc.whatever.com>,77777
2024-02-06T20:00:00,abcdabcd-1234-1234-6666-9999999999999,other@other.cc,7.7.7.7,12341234,\Temp,<cccccc4@aaabbbccc.whatever.com>,888888
2024-02-06T20:00:00,abcdabcd-1234-1234-6666-9999999999999,other@other.cc,7.7.7.7,12341234,\Temp,<final3@host.gmail.com>,99999
```

To do the conversion to CSV using `jq` in place of Miller, replace the `mlr` command with something like

```bash
jq -s -r '(first|keys|@csv), map([.[]]|@csv)[]'
```

This would pick the keys from the first input object as the CSV headers and would CSV-format all values into one record per object.